# NullPointerException when using executeQuery

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I have a null pointer exception in

```
ResultSet rs = aStatement.executeQuery(Query); // it can't be executed
```

my code is like this :

```
 public static boolean testLogin(String user, String password) throws SQLException {
    String Query = "select * from TBL_Users where userName = '" + user + "' and  passWord = '" + password + "' ";
    ResultSet rs = aStatement.executeQuery(Query);

    while (rs.next()) {

        info.Id = rs.getInt("ID");
        info.userName = rs.getString("userName");
        info.Name = rs.getString("User_Name");
        info.Password = rs.getString("passWord");
        info.isAdmin = rs.getBoolean("Admin");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: What is `aStatement` referring to?

Comment: 1. you didn't show us the stack trace. That can eliminate 90% of problems. 2. you've got problems in your resultset handling code.

Comment: Exactly, from where does come that `aStatement`? A private field that is not initialized in the constructor?

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux: That was a rhetorical question :)

Comment: Please show the definition of 'aStatement'.

Answer (score 9):

Most likely `aStatement` is null.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you think aStatement should not be null, but it is.

This is bad JDBC code, for many reasons:

1. No cleanup of resources.
2. Doesn't use PreparedStatement
3. Keeps creating the query string over and over again instead of using a static variable
4. Doesn't follow Java coding standards ("Query" should be "query")

Here's another way to write it.  Start with an interface:

```
package persistence;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public interface CredentialDao
{
    boolean isValidUser(String username, String password) throws SQLException;
}
```

Write an implementation:

```
package persistence;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class CredentialDaoImpl implements CredentialDao
{
    private static final String CREDENTIAL_QUERY = "SELECT COUNT() FROM USER WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?";

    private Connection connection;

    public CredentialDaoImpl(Connection connection)
    {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public boolean isValidUser(String username, String password) throws SQLException
    {
        boolean isValidUser = false;

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try
        {
            ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(CREDENTIAL_QUERY);
            ps.setString(1, username);
            ps.setString(2, password);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next())
            {
                int count = rs.getInt(1);
                isValidUser = (count > 0);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            DatabaseUtils.close(rs);
            DatabaseUtils.close(ps);
        }

        return isValidUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: A DAO that stores a `Connection` in a field? That doesn't seem like a very good idea to me....

Comment: Connection is your issue, Jaydee?  If the connection isn't shared, but is checked out of a pool for each thread, this class would be thread safe.

Comment: @ColinD - The Spring idiom is to inject the connection into the DAO.  How else can a DAO participate in a transaction with other DAOs?  What's your alternative - have the DAO create its own Connection?  I thought all this was why connection pools were invented.

Comment: @duffymo: I've never seen injected Connections... just injected DataSources. You typically need to call `close()` on a pooled connection to return it to the pool so other things can use it, and you typically want to do that as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's only data sources that are injected in with Spring.  And I don't call close on the data source; if I'm doing Spring JDBC, the DAOs extend SimpleJdbcTemplate, which handles all the plumbing for me.  Since this is straight JDBC, and no Spring, I made the Connection pass in explicit to make a point: The DAO is given its access to the data source; it doesn't create it.

Comment: @duffymo: Right, `SimpleJdbcTemplate` handles that stuff for you... but somewhere in the plumbing, it has to call `close()` on a `Connection` once it's finished with it for a particular request/transaction to return it to the pool (or actually close it if it isn't pooled for some reason, obviously). I'm just saying that rather than injecting a `Connection` (which is something that should be held for as short a time as possible), a `DataSource` should really be injected and used to retrieve a `Connection` for each DAO method call.

Comment: @ColinD - I used Connection because I was trying to provide an example without writing all of Spring or an entire app.  You're most welcome to do so and add it to the mix if you're inclined.  I stand by my answer - I think it's perfectly acceptable, defensible, and usable as written.  The service that owns the DAO should create the Connection, pass it on, and close it in the narrowest scope possible.  It can be done without a DataSource.

Answer (score 1):

The `aStatement` variable is apparently `null`, please validate that it is correctly set. You should consider read the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) and make sure you use the lower camel case for variables and java bean conventions.

For code snippets in **stackoverflow** if they are not self-explanatory, you should obey the rules of the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), this will help you to get more and better answers. Also you should provide a stack trace with the occured exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use [prepared statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

```
    Connection con = ...; // obtain connection here
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from TBL_Users where userName = ?'");
    pstmt.setInt(1, userName);

    ResultSet rs = pstmt .executeQuery();
...
// do clean up here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (rs.next()) {

    info.Id = rs.getInt("ID");
    info.userName = rs.getString("userName");
    info.Name = rs.getString("User_Name");
    info.Password = rs.getString("passWord");
    info.isAdmin = rs.getBoolean("Admin");
    return true;       //                                Huh? What?
}
```

What is `info` refering to and why is there a `return` imediatly after the assignments?